# npm run prod generates an error even though npm run dev works without any error

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm

I am creating website with laravel and vue.js.

When I run 'npm run dev', there is no error shown in the console.
However, if I run 'npm run prod', there is a error down below.

```
Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at i (app.js 1)
```

```json
function i(e) {
        if (n[e])
            return n[e].exports;
        var r = n[e] = {
            i: e,
            l: !1,
            exports: {}
        };

//console says that this line's 'i' is the cause of the error.
        return t[e].call(r.exports, r, r.exports, i),

        r.l = !0,
        r.exports
    }
    i.e = function(t) {
```

I have no idea what this ' i ' is and where it came from.
is there any way to find out the cause or solution through this js file?

If you need more information to solve this problem, please let me know.
Thank you for your cooperation.

Update

I found the reason why this error occurred.

The page where the error occurs is photo list page.
If I try to render each photo with using each component, the error happens.

for example...

```json
<template>
    <div class="photo-list" ontouchstart="">
        <h2 v-show="noPhoto">There are no photos in this page.</h2>
        <div class="images" v-for="photo in photos" :key="photo.url">
            <PhotoComponent v-bind:item=photo></PhotoComponent>
        </div>
        <PaginateComponent :current-page="currentPage" :last-page="lastPage"></PaginateComponent>
    </div>
</template>
```

On the other hand, if I try to render a photo without using component, the error is disappeared.

for example...

```json
<template>
    <div class="photo-list" ontouchstart="">
        <h2 v-show="noPhoto">There are no photos in this page.</h2>
        <div class="images" v-viewer="{movable: false}">
            <a class="luminous" v-for="photo in photos">
                <img class="item" :src="photo.url" :key="photo.url"
                     alt="This photo taken by~~~.">
            </a>
        </div>
        <PaginateComponent :current-page="currentPage" :last-page="lastPage"></PaginateComponent>
    </div>
</template>
```

However, I do not know why this difference trigger the error.

Comment: Are you using any environment variables during production?

Comment: @ChristopherDias what is environment variable? could you give me some example?  FYI, I pasted the 'npm run prod' detail. I hope it helps you.                     
```cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"```,